# WooCommerce Checkout based on countries

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm trying to base my checkout page to different countries.
I'm know using "geolocation" to base the currency for different countries.
But payment solution still remains..

Exemple, If I'm buy a product in Norway I want PayPal as a payment solution.

If I buy a product in Sweden, I want Klarna Checkout as payment method.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]'); ?> = PayPal
<?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_klarna_checkout]'); ?> = Klarna
```

I have found different solutions but, still not how I want it.

I tried this, but still dosen't work.

```
//  Disable gateway based on country
function payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways ) {
global $woocommerce;
if ( isset( $available_gateways['paypal'] ) && $woocommerce->customer->get_country() <> 'SE' ) {
    unset(  $available_gateways['paypal'] );
}
return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_country' );
```

Comment: *"I have found different solutions but, still not how I want it."* You're going to have to be more specific about what you tried, what you want, and exactly where you are having trouble.

Comment: Simple, If I sit in Norway and purchases from my site I want PayPal as a payment method.
If I sit in Sweden and purchases from my site I want Klarna as a payment method. @Chris

Comment: @Esster that doesn't explain what you tried and where what you tried fell short.

Comment: @helgatheviking I have tried google searching and the code above.. with no success.. I came here to Stackoverflow for one reason. And that reason was for help... I don't know how to do that I just tell you, but I have a speculation. And that speculation is a code who has if/else. I want a solution that makes my payment based on different countries. As I say. If I purchases from Norway location. The browser feel "aha" this country has Paypal as a payment method. And If I sit in Sweden and surfing around on my web, the browser recognize my location and switch to Klarna as payment method.